# `/me/associated` gives ambiguous/wrong response

Tags: support, bug, api-v2.2

[This is my associated accounts page](http://stackexchange.com/users/6482771/amit-jha?tab=accounts). No where I can see [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) profile. But when I run [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) with `meta_site` as parameter to `types`, I get a response that tells me that I have a profile in Meta Stack Overflow, which is ambiguous.

Also, when I don't give `types` parameter, it will give me all the associated accounts (it is not given in documentation, but understood), i.e., if the account is in `meta_site` or `main_site`, it will give me all the accounts. This time it doesn't give my `Meta Stack Overflow profile`. Again ambiguous response.

Comment: Your associated accounts page does too show your MSE profile if, and only if, you have one.  It's been that way for years

Comment: [`types=main_site` in `/me/associated` gives `meta_site` accounts also](http://stackapps.com/q/6796) is another thing.